# Как мне округлить это одно значение? Ведь все числа он правильно округляет, а это нет

Tags: python, round

Выполняются из 107 почти все, кроме одного, и я не могу понять почему так.

```
def litres(time):
    rounded_time = round(time)
    return((rounded_time // 2))
```

```
>>> Passed: 106 Failed: 1 Exit Code: 1
>>> should return 5 litres: 6 should equal 5
```

Задание:

> Натан любит кататься на велосипеде.
>
> Поскольку Натан знает, как важно поддерживать гидрацию, он выпивает 0,5 литра воды за час езды на велосипеде.
>
> Вам даётся время в часах, и вам нужно вернуть количество литров, которые выпьет Натан, округлённое до наименьшего значения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**округление до наименьшего значения** - это отбрасывание дробной части, что легко делает `int()`

а вы именно округляете по правилам округления через `round()`